# Neo4j relation write performance with Neo4j.Driver.V1

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, database-performance

I'm evaluating Neo4j for use as a data store in an interactive application. With the code below I'm getting around 40 ms for adding a relation which would be way too slow for our needs as our models can have tens of thousands of relations.
Is this typical performance? Any tips for improving the code? I've tested with 12 relation types and a total of 6652 relations.

```
using (var session = driver.Session())
{
    foreach (var relationType in relationTypes)
    {
        var nodeArray = relationType.Value.Select(n => new Dictionary<string, string> {{"from", n.Item1}, {"to", n.Item2}}).ToArray();
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"nodes", nodeArray}};
        var relationCommand =
            string.Format(
                "UNWIND $nodes as node WITH node.from as from, node.to as to "
              + "MATCH (f {{nodeId:from}}), (t {{nodeId:to}}) "
              + "CREATE (f)-[:" + relationType.Key + "]->(t) ");
        session.Run(relationCommand, dictionary);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't use any labels and so no unique constraints/indices. Your query is just unoptimized at all

Comment: It certainly is unoptimized. :) OK, so labels are needed to make MATCH efficient?

Comment: Labels + an indexed/unique constraint on the property you match on (here nodeId) so lookups are O(1) + 1 : label + property

Comment: Excellent advise, that cut the time to around 1.5 ms per relation. Feel free to write it up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Added an answer in a detailed way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using labels combined with an indexed property on which to match on makes queries extremely non-performant.

So best :

Add labels to your nodes.

`CREATE (n:Label {id: 1})` for eg when creating nodes, or if you want to add a generic label to your already created nodes you can do

```
MATCH (n) SET n:Label
```

Then create a unique constraint for your nodeId property :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Label) ASSERT n.nodeId IS UNIQUE
```

Then use it in your query  :

```
var relationCommand =
            string.Format(
                "UNWIND $nodes as node WITH node.from as from, node.to as to "
              + "MATCH (f:Label {{nodeId:from}}), (t:Label {{nodeId:to}}) "
              + "CREATE (f)-[:" + relationType.Key + "]->(t) ");
        session.Run(relationCommand, dictionary);
```

Enjoy the difference !